# Use XGetPointerMapping/XSetPointerMapping to swap mouse buttons

Tags: linux, x11

I have found these two APIs at http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetpointermapping. I think that they can be used to swap mouse buttons on linux or mac system. I used it in following way:

```
            Display *   curdisp;    // Current display.
    char        curmap[MAX_NUM];// Current mapping.
    int         nmap;       // number of mappings.

curdisp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

nmap    = XGetPointerMapping(curdisp, curmap, MAX_NUM);
if(!nmap)
    return -1;

if(curmap[0] == '1' && curmap[2] == '3') {
    curmap[0] = '3';
    curmap[2] = '1';
} else {
    curmap[0] = '1';
    curmap[2] = '3';
}

//Set the mapping.
nmap    = XSetPointerMapping(curdisp, curmap, nmap);
```

But the call XSetPointerMapping returns 0 and there is no effect on mouse button.
Can anyone give some example of swapping mouse button using XSetPointerMapping? or How to use it correctly? Will it work immediately?

The OS being used is Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button numbers are stored as unsigned char but are not stored as characters. 
Change '1' and '3' to 1 and 3.

Your code maps them to buttons 49 and 51 and does affect the buttons making button 1 and 3 unusable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed '1' to 1 and '3' to 3. But XSetPointerMapping returns 0. Even after running it under sudo, it is returning zero and there is no impact on mouse button. What is the meaning of 0 as a return value? I am quite new to X Windows programming.

Comment: Works for me and I get a zero return so I think it is ok. Try printing the map values to check them. The only other change I made was to use unsigned char.

Comment: Is the same program working fine for you? Do I miss something for curdisp? I am running this code on Mac OS (Mountain Lion 10.7.4). On this machine, it is not running. I have not tested so far in linux machine.

Comment: I'm using Linux. I just copy and pasted your code and changed the char to unsigned char.  I put a main function round it and defined MAX_NUM as 100. I then compiled and ran it.  At this point mouse buttons 1 and 3 stopped doing anything so I knew it had done something.

Comment: Is there any Cocoa equivalent to swap mouse buttons?

Comment: I think that why it is not working on Mac OS X because Mac OS does not use X11 by default and this program will change the pointer mappings on X11 based system. That is why it is running there. But in Mac OS X, I think I need another function (most probably in their Windowing system). Is it possible to do it programmatically on Mac OS X using their native programming.